# android studio - How do I resize buttons based on text?

Tags: android, android-button

I'm making two buttons.

if One button is clicked, the other button's text is changed.

I coded initial status using setText

```
mBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
mBtn.setText("Connect");
```

and changing text using

```
mBtn.setText("Disconnect");
```

In this case, button's length is fixed initial length.

What can i do?

[image]

Comment: @sudesh 's answer should work. If it does't, please add you layout xml in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this on your layout it will work. remove fixed width first.

```
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Button

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Connect"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    />
```